# Using kotlin with Mvvmfx framework

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, mvvmfx

I'm developing a desktop application with JavaFx.
I'm interested in using Mvvmfx as a framework and wonder if it is possible to use Kotlin with Mvvmfx to avoid all boilerplate code ?

Is there an example of this somewhere ?

Comment: Kotlin is fully interoperable with Java so yes you can use Kotlin with any Java library.

Comment: Have you looked into TornadoFX? It has excellent support for MVVM workflows. https://tornadofx.io/

Comment: There is no official example for this combination. However, I don't think there is anything in the API of mvvmFX that prevents usage with kotlin. If you find any problems with kotlin please file an issue in the [mvvmfx issue tracker](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/issues) at github and I will take a look at it. Additionally, if we find the time we will add an example for kotlin in the future.